# Django StaticFiles APP and Wsgi

Tags: django, mod-wsgi, vhosts

It's not so easy questions as others.. at least. it's not a problem to setup simple one-dir-based static files location..

https://bitbucket.org/sirex/django-starter/src

There's such an interesting project in here.. this one is using distribute and buildout for making whole project and django with modules in one dir. you can migrate from dev to production mode easy and etc.. all you need is just to rename dir, and type "make" in it, and that's it =) there's manual in there...

Situation which works with python server, and don't work with apache mod_wsgi:
Default static files location is: "var/htdocs/static". This can be overridden with one static dir location for example apps/myapp/myapp/static/. This works with python webserver but doesn't work with wsgi/apache. wsgi can't see anything apart default directory.. example: http://localhost:8000/static/css/main.css works but with apache same url doesn't work. and this file lies in myproject/apps/myapp/myapp/static/css/main.css although default static dir is var/htdocs/static =)

As far as I understand this overriding made with StaticFiles application in settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BUILDOUT_DIR, 'var', 'htdocs', 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
  os.path.join(BUILDOUT_DIR, 'project', 'static'), # <-- why "project" and not "apps" I don't know X_X
)
```

maybe this one is incorrect, I don't know but with py-server this works. apache vhost works with default location.. and setuped to "var/htdocs/static".

Maybe problem is in wsgi script?

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python2.6

import os,sys
sys.path[0:0] = [
    '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/',
    '/www/webapp/visimes/eggs/PIL-1.1.7-py2.6-freebsd-8.1-RELEASE-amd64.egg',
    '/www/webapp/visimes/eggs/South-0.7.3-py2.6.egg',
    '/www/webapp/visimes/eggs/django_annoying-0.7.6-py2.6.egg',
    '/www/webapp/visimes/eggs/coverage-3.4-py2.6-freebsd-8.1-RELEASE-amd64.egg',
    '/www/webapp/visimes/eggs/django_debug_toolbar-0.8.4-py2.6.egg',
    '/www/webapp/visimes/eggs/django_extensions-0.6-py2.6.egg',
    '/www/webapp/visimes/eggs/django_test_utils-0.3-py2.6.egg',
    '/www/webapp/visimes/eggs/ipdb-0.3-py2.6.egg',
    '/www/webapp/visimes/eggs/ipython-0.10.1-py2.6.egg',
    '/www/webapp/visimes/eggs/djangorecipe-0.21-py2.6.egg',
    '/www/webapp/visimes/eggs/zc.recipe.egg-1.3.2-py2.6.egg',
    '/www/webapp/visimes/eggs/zc.buildout-1.5.2-py2.6.egg',
    '/www/webapp/visimes/eggs/BeautifulSoup-3.2.0-py2.6.egg',
    '/www/webapp/visimes/eggs/setuptools-0.6c12dev_r88795-py2.6.egg',
    '/www/webapp/visimes/parts/django',
    '/www/webapp/visimes',
    '/www/webapp/visimes/project', # <-- this one need for monitor.py which i put in there
    '/www/webapp/visimes/apps/portal', # <-- startapp.sh script some how forgot to add this dir, it's my default app dir, which must be generated with startapp.sh and added in here..
    ]

import djangorecipe.wsgi

if __name__ == '__main__':
    djangorecipe.manage.main('project.development')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'project.development'

import monitor
monitor.start(interval=1.0)

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

I added last 4 lines by my self. because I couldn't start apache.. I'm guessing that djangorecipe.wsgi should handle everything else with staticFile override.. anyway please, check out that package, if you on linux or mac, and try it by your self. it must work

ps. (btw bin/django need to dublicated as bin/django.wsgi and etc/apache.conf is generated vhost for apache)

I'd really apriciated if somebody would try to launch this "Starter" manually with wsgi... then you'd understand everything.=)

Edit: Any information about how can WSGI understand where he needs to search static files apart default location from django settings, is REALLY appreciated =)

Comment: You pointed an alias within your apache config to server static files in /your/path/to/static/?

Comment: what about this one? http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django-admin-collectstatic how this thing works? it can collect static files from multiple location?

Comment: Again, Apache (or any other webserver) can only serve static files if you add an Alias to the Apache config which is pointing to the location which is hosting your static files. And yes, you should use collectstatic command to collect all your static files into one location (for convenience or bcs. you don't want to set many Alias to different locations). The staticfiles app is mainly there for helping you develop on the local dev server without doing something like collectstatic or adding an Alias to your server config. On production the only usage is having STATIC_URL in your templates.

Comment: see http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/modwsgi/#serving-media-files for more infos about how to handle media/static files on production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No way of having some kind of overriding like django does with WSGI..

there's great command in django "manage.py collectstatic" which places all files from STATIC_DIR list (in settings.py) to main static directory.. in fact this commands just copy files from all those dir's and that's it =)

Would be great to know, how could I make this copying automatic when any file in that dir would be updated.. same thing like monitor.py for automatic wsgi reload when source is modified...

Answer (score 2):

There is lots of documentation on the official mod_wsgi site for understanding how to use it. This includes how to set it up for serving static media files. See:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/IntegrationWithDjango
  http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickConfigurationGuide
  http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationGuidelines

Answer (score 1):

WSGI has **nothing whatever to do** with serving static files. This is all clearly covered in the Django deployment documentation - as Torsten suggests in the comments, you'll need to point Apache at your static files, probably via an alias.

I must say though that this project looks very dodgy. Manually adding a load of eggs to `sys.path` is not the right way to go about things - a much better way would be to use something like virtualenv, which manages all that for you.

Comment: What about it? That's a management command that collects your static files into one place, which is then directly served by Apache.

Comment: Comment about the "manual" sys.path: no, that's not manual, that's buildout that autmoatically inserted it there. It is buildout's way of achieving a virtualenv-like isolation. (The advantage of this sys.path method is that you don't have to activate a virtualenv, it is all set correctly, which helps when running inside apache/iis).